# Angular 2 - Why is the binding of dynamic components broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I generate a compnent dynamically

```
var componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TransportOrderComponent);

let dynamicComponent = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

The bindings of the properties within the dynamic compoment don't work. (e. g. ngIf, button click, ...)

Component html:

```
<button (click)="show = !show">toggle: {{show ? 'hide' : 'show'}}</button>
<br>
<div *ngIf="show"> Text to show</div>
```

Component TypeScript:

```
...
export class TransportOrderComponent {
  show: boolean = true;
}
```

As static component everything works fine. If I add the dyn component and click the static components button the content of the dynamic component changes **once**

[image]

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qTLSyVdce2YxjbgOF7sX?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're running code outside angular zone.

This should work for you

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone, ...) {}

addTransportOrderComponent(jqContainer: any) {
  this.zone.run(() => {
     let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TransportOrderComponent);
     let dynamicComponent = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
  })
}
```

**[Modified Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ARk5BsS3Pvjp9WBoGIGC?p=preview)**